# Creating a tab view programmatically with Cocoa/Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How do I create a tab view programmatically using Objective-C and Cocoa?

Answer (score 13):

This adds a tab view to a window:

```
   NSTabView *tabView = [[[NSTabView alloc]
      initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(10,10,300,300)] autorelease];
   [[window contentView] addSubview:tabView];
```

This adds a tab to the tab view:

```
   NSTabViewItem *item = [[[NSTabViewItem alloc]
      initWithIdentifier:@"tab1"] autorelease];
   [item setLabel:@"Tab 1"];
   [tabView addTabViewItem:item];
```

At this point you'll want to add some controls to the tab. You should definitely do this with interface builder. Create a nib with a view, make the file owner a NSViewController. Then do the following:

```
   NSViewController *viewController = [[[NSViewController alloc]
      initWithNibName:@"myView" bundle:nil] autorelease];
   [item setView:[viewController view]];
```

Comment: Thank for your comments I'll try this.  As far as your final comment goes I cannot use the interface builder because I am trying to build this tab view as a widget that can be used with a version of lisp that uses an objective c bridge.  I am not just trying to build an app that has a tab view which is why I was asking about how to do all this programatically.

Comment: You should still be able to use NSViewController. In fact, you can probably assemble the tab view (and its subviews) in IB and use NSViewController to load that.